# How to properly model a "selected item" relationship in SQL databases?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-modeling

I am making a database using the Entity Framework. Right now, my problem is:

I've got the ASP.NET User entity (`ApplicationUser`). I also have another user entity (`LynxUser`). The relationship between them is: Every `ApplicationUser` can open one or more `LynxUser` accounts. Every `ApplicationUser` must be logged into one and only one of them at a time. When registering an `ApplicationUser` account, a `LynxUser` is registered too. I don't need to worry about security with the `LynxUser` accounts, the only requirement is that an `ApplicationUser` may use only their own accounts.

I have difficulties modelling this in a way that EF will like. Right now, my code looks like (edited for brevity):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {

    [Display(Name = "Active User", AutoGenerateField = false), InverseProperty("SelecterUser")]
    public LynxUser ActiveUser { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ApplicationUser")]
    public ICollection<LynxUser> LynxUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class LynxUser {
    [Key, Display(Name = "User name", AutoGenerateField = true), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1),
        Editable(false, AllowInitialValue = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Site User", AutoGenerateField = false), Editable(false, AllowInitialValue = true),
        InverseProperty("LynxUsers")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is required to establish a one-to-one transferrable relationship as the active user.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Selecter User", AutoGenerateField = false), InverseProperty("ActiveUser")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser SelecterUser { get; set; }

}
```

The problem seems to be the recursive relationship between these two entities. How can I better model this? I absolutely do need to record the last `LynxUser` every `ApplicationUser` was logged in to.

EDIT: Problem solved, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a "IsActive" - boolean flag to the LynxUser and remove the *ActiveUser* from the *ApplicationUser*.

So you just had to set the "IsActive" flag. The ApplicationUser just knows which LynxUsers it have.

Comment: I'd still like to keep the convenience of having it easily accesible and making sure there is only one active `LynxUser` per `ApplicationUser`. I will do this if there is no other solution.

Comment: I know what you want to achive. But I think this should not be a task of your DataBase. You should handle this by yourself. In your first thoughts you also need to set the `ActiveUser` by yourself. So you just have to change the `IsActive` flag of all `LynxUsers` when the active users changed

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding another entity, LynxLogin, that tracks the `ApplicationUser` to `LynxUser` logins, along with a `DateTime`. I still had some problems actually generating the new objects and writing them to the database (I had to manually set `db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` to prevent `db.SaveChanges()` from complaining that the user already exists.